# Настройка двух мониторов для двух приложений в Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, x11, автозагрузка, видеокарта

Дано: видеокарта с двумя видеовыходами (обычно NVidia какой-то версии).... 
Есть приложение, работающее с X11, использующее OpenGL, например, glxgears.
Нужно запустить два таких приложения на старте системы (через .xsession), но на двух мониторах независимо. Совсем не разбираюсь с настройками видеокарт и X серверов. Может кто подскажет, как разделить видеовыходы между двумя (?) X серверами? Вход от клавиатур и "мышей" не так важны... Важно, чтобы видеовыходы карты независимые были для приложений.

Comment: Можно обойтись и одним сервером, но как разделить мониторы по выходам?

Answer (score 1):

Ахренительно трудно без специального железа и специального софта под это железо. Во всяком случае на тот момент (с год наверное назад) как мой коллега копал этот вопрос и рассказывал мне. Суть заключается в настройках памяти расположения дисплеев внутри видеокарты. Называется это [EDID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) и из-за копирастичнсти есть только в картах профессионального уровня типа Quadro и FirePro. Может в Wayland что-то такое и запилят (или уже запилили), но на старых системах всё плохо.